# Write data to json file using Protractor

Tags: protractor, protractor-net, gulp-protractor

I have a code to read data from json file using protractor and it works properly. For that I created json file in project folder. Then included that test data file in test scripts pages by using 
'var data = require('../testdata.json')"

I am reading the file in follwing way:
Example:

testdata.json file:

{
"Name":"Json Test Data",
"Purpose":"Storing test data"
}

Usage:
"data.Name" retrieved value is"Json Test Data"
"data.Purpose" retrieved value is "Storing test data"

Now I need to write some text using protractor to that json file from which we read the values.
e.g. 
The original json file should have extra data written from protractor code.

{
"Name":"Json Test Data",
"Purpose":"Storing test data",
"user1":"email@email.com"
}

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: write a file: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Thanks martin770 for the help.

Comment: //The code to write to the file is below: 
const fs = require('fs');
fs.appendFile('Filename.json', 'TexttoBeWritenToFile', (err) => {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log('Result saved to file saved!');
});

Answer (score 4):

This will work.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var text = "Text To be Written"
var outputFilename = 'Output.json';
fs.writeFile(outputFilename, text, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("JSON saved to " + outputFilename);
    }
});
```

Comment: is there an extraneous "fs" in the second to last line? also the indentation is off and somewhat misleading in the line before "else"

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript:

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';

writeFile(filename: string, fileContents: string): void {
    fs.writeFile(filename, fileContents, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log(`File saved to ${ filename }`);
        }
    });
}
```